# Ruby 'rails server' issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

Been getting an error everytime I try to run 'rails server'

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

I have tried following the other tips such as bundle install and update but still same problem. Tried to rvm install 1.9.3 and got:

```
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.....
Installing required packages: gcc49.......
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install gcc49',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/Quoc/.rvm/log/1457707600_ruby-1.9.3-p551/package_install_gcc49.log
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 1 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation
++ case "$_system_version" in
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Brew repair didnt work either.

EDIT: result from running `brew install gcc46 --env=std`

```
==> make bootstrap
Last 15 lines from /Users/Quoc/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gcc46/02.make:
      _lto_end_uncompression in libbackend.a(lto-compress.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      _lto_end_uncompression in libbackend.a(lto-compress.o)
  "_inflateInit_", referenced from:
      _lto_end_uncompression in libbackend.a(lto-compress.o)
  "_zError", referenced from:
      _lto_end_compression in libbackend.a(lto-compress.o)
      _lto_end_uncompression in libbackend.a(lto-compress.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [cc1] Error 1
rm gcc.pod
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install these dependences manually, try

```
brew install automake
```

if it gives you error of missing link of automake something like this

You must `brew link autoconf` before automake can be installed
then try these commands

```
brew link --overwrite --dry-run autoconf

brew link --overwrite autoconf

brew install automake
```

it will install automake and then you can try again to install ruby.

If it doesn't work you can try another thing:

Sol2:

```
brew install gcc46 --env=std
brew install gcc; brew install gcc46 --cc=gcc-4.9
Manually build GCC 4.6 outside of Homebrew, using the same configure switches
```

Also you can try with this :

```
$ brew install gcc
$ CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 rvm install 1.9.1-p376 --enable-shared
```

Comment: `brew install automake` comes up with `Warning: automake-1.15 already installed`.

Comment: Then try the rest of the command. Let me know if it is working or not

Comment: result is in my edit post above. would it be worth completely uninstalling brew and rails and everything related to ruby and start all over? if so can you give the commands to do it

Comment: it would be better to start over. Follow this tutorial https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: Yeah sure. you need to uninstall everything at first.